# Mediacom FelxBook edge 13 - Linux Mint 19.2 Touchscreeen & Touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, touch-screen

I just had my fingers on a Mediacom FelxBook edge 13. I'm quite happy with it--everything but the touchscreen and touchpad on a fresh Linux Mint 19.2 installation works out of the box. Can anyone please help me figure out how to fix that?

I saw the touchscreen working twice on a live session and than no more (only twice and without any understandable pattern). The machine have a Windows 10 instance on a second HD and the touchscreen and touchpad are working well on that system.

Here you have `xinput list` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4GHz keyboard and mouse                 id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2.4GHz keyboard and mouse                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ 2.4GHz keyboard and mouse                 id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen             id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 PC Camera: PC Camera              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:3841 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1ea7:0066  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```